# AttributeError: module 'lyrics' has no attribute 'Domain'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having troubles with making my code running in Python3 (it was in Python2 and I am converting it).

Here is the project structure:

```
lyrics/__init__.py
lyrics/lyrics.py
./manifold.py
```

in *manifold.py* :

```
import lyrics as lyr

lyr.Domain(label="Points", data=X)
```

where *Domain* class is defined in *lyrics/lyrics.py*:

```
class Domain(object):
   ...
```

When I execute *manifold.py* with:

```
./manifold.py
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./manifold.py", line 76, in
>
> Points = lyr.Domain(label="Points", data=X) AttributeError: module 'lyrics' has no attribute 'Domain'

Any idea ?

Thank you

[EDIT]
in *lyrics/**init**.py*

```
from lyrics import *
from . import functions
```

Comment: IIUC, the name `lyrics` refer to the top level folder. You gotta do `from lyrics import lyrics`

Comment: @rafaelc actually the "import lyrics as lyr" is in the original code in python2, and I think it intents to really import the folder....

Comment: do you have a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: yes, sorry I will update my post

Comment: Did you try what I said? `lyrics.lyrics.Domain` ? Or `from lyrics import lyrics` then `lyrics.Domain`

Comment: yes **from lyrics import lyrics as lyr** did the trick, So I guess it imports not just the lyrics.py files inside lyrics folder, BUT the whole *lyrics* folder... Not sure to understand but it workd

Comment: The name `lyrics` there refer to the module. You could have many files in this module, each with their own types, logics etc. You may control what is imported with the `__init__.py` file.